# Installing and configure docular

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install and configure doculare package on node.js platform. I have started from the official documentation website [grunt-docular.com](http://grunt-docular.com).

After hundreds of tries, there was a problem in running `grunt docular-server`.
I think the problem in the compatibility between `docular` package and its grunt plugin `grunt-docular`.

When I tried to use `docular@0.7.2` and `grunt-docular@0.1.2` it worked. But the target is to use the latest versions of `npm` packages to get the newest version of angular docs.

The error was :

`Warning: Task "docular-server" not found. Use --force to continue.`

`Aborted due to warnings.`

Here is what I did:

```
npm install grunt-docular
```

and this is my grunt config file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    docular: {
        groups: [],
        showDocularDocs: true,
        showAngularDocs: true
    }

});

// Load the plugin that provides the "docular" tasks.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-docular');

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['docular']);
};
```

Comment: I have same problem plz help us :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.
It seems that for the latest version of grunt-docular to run the server you must run:

```
grunt docularserver
```

If doing that you run into an error of the type "path.join expects strings", you must add the following to your grunt config file:

```
docularserver: {
    targetDir: "//path to where the docs are generated"
}
```

Comment: yes, that worked for me.